# SearchView getting reset when moved from one fragment to other in viewpager android

Tags: android, filter, searchview

I have been working on an application where I have 6 tabs each of them having a listview in it. I want to filter the listview in each fragment depending upon the text in SearchView which is part of MainActivity. I have a working code for filtering records written in Listview adapter.

The issue is, whenever I want to search something using searchview, the current fragment listview gets filtered but as soon as I move from one fragment to other, the searchview gets reset and the text written in gets clear. That's why I don't get anything in other fragment to search for.

I have following code logic used

In MainActivity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_order, menu);

    if(searchView == null)
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
```

In each of the fragment I have :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    android.view.MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView sv = new SearchView(((OrderActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (listAdapter != null) {
        listAdapter.filter(newText);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please suggest for solution on above issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this

Comment: Yes I am now using custom edittext in place of SearchView and updating the list using broadcast receiver

Comment: I gave answer to same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43934756/6865663). Hope it's helps for you.