# Searchview Move to right Side when Clearing

Tags: android, searchview

I have androidx Searchview in my app's toolbar.It is working fine. But the problem is when i clicked on Listview item the new activity starts and i clear Searchview in onItemClicked method and when i press back. Searchview is moved towards left and title is gone. I tried to search the solution but could not find it.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu,menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_Search);
    searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Type Here to Search");
    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                adapter.getFilter().filter("");
                listView.clearTextFilter();
            }
            else
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
           position, long id) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position",position);
            startActivity(intent);
            searchView.setIconfied(true);
            searchView.setIconfied(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29531413/12722872

Comment: I tried it. It is working but the icon is moving towards left side. How to solve this?
 @MustafaYanık